# PHP code generating PHP Notice

Tags: php

I get this diagnostic message from PHP about the code below:

> `PHP Notice: Use of undefined constant default_output - assumed 'default_output'`

```
protected static $instance = NULL;

public static function instance() {
    NULL === self::$instance and self::$instance = new self;
    return self::$instance;
}
```

What does this message mean and how do I rejigger the code to kill the message?

Comment: Search your code for `default_output`.  (There's more code than this, right?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply you have somewhere in your code `default_output`. And it should be probably `$default_output`